# What pronouns should I use to refer to humanity?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I am writing an essay on existential risks and I want to refer to humanity but also need to say "we" and "our" in order to make the delivery of the message practical to each of us while also not seeming robotic.

I have provided two examples of two sentences from the introduction, one uses "our" and the other uses "it". Which way is the correct way to refer to humanity? I think the correct way is to use "it" but that really alienates humanity and removes the human connection.

1. For the first 200,000 years of **its** existence, humanity has successfully navigated the multitude of natural existential risks from **its** environment. Yet, we are at a unique point in history where the principal threat of existential catastrophe no longer comes from the environment, but rather humanity itself; not only threatening the progress we made, but the potential that **could be fulfilled**.
2. For the first 200,000 years of **our** existence, humanity has successfully navigated the multitude of natural existential risks from **our** environment. Yet, we are at a unique point in history where the principal threat of existential catastrophe no longer comes from the environment, but rather humanity itself; not only threatening the progress we have made, but the potential that **we could fulfill**.

Comment: Use either. You clearly appreciate the nuances that are created, so choose which you want. And please note my edits: *principal* is **not** synonymous with *principle*!

Comment: @anton thanks for recognizing "principal". Is using "our" wrong? It is for a scholarship and I dont want to make the wrong choice but also dont want to come off as cold/alienated.

Comment: With regard to your latter refinement, you're really asking about style matters, and domain-related ones at that, and this is really beyond the scope of ELU questions. The question asks for the sort of specialist advice that only those well versed in the requirements of the examination body involved are equipped to give. Anton comments that neither approach is ungrammatical, the ELU answer. // Note however that (1) pairs 'its' with 'we' anyway, which purists might quibble with (but which I, who don't want a scholarship, would use if I did not believe in a recent earth).

Comment: @PeterRandall  Because this question feels more like writing advice than anything else, please be aware that misspelling basic words like *don’t* and *principle* is likely to reflect far worse on the writer than any quibbles over humanity’s preferred pronouns ever shall. You need to first decide which grammatical person *humanity* should represent: first, second, or third. Then you can move on to its grammatical number. What does prior art indicate here?

Comment: In my opinion, #1 is correct and #2 is incorrect.

Comment: **(A)** In (1) you are mixing "It" & "We" , making it inconsistent ; In (2) "We" & "Our" is consistent. **(B)** Humanity includes me & you ; We should Ideally use "We" ! While talking about Plants or Planets, Continents or Mountains, Aliens or Robots, we should not use "We" , because we are not included !!